# Window buttons (close etc.) not showing at first time

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a vertical split view in the main view controller. I set the left custom view's background color. Then the three window buttons got invisible at first time after launch. But there ARE buttons on the title bar because I can tap the zoom button and make the window being fullscreen. Then I pressed esc to quit fullscreen mode. And the three buttons became visible. Please tell me why. I want them to be displayed from start up.
[image: after launching]
after launching

[image: after quitting full screen mode]
after quitting full screen mode

Some code:

1. in window controller

   ```
   override func windowDidLoad() {
       super.windowDidLoad()

       window!.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
       window!.titleVisibility = .hidden
       window!.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
       window!.styleMask = [NSWindow.StyleMask.fullSizeContentView, NSWindow.StyleMask.titled, NSWindow.StyleMask.closable, NSWindow.StyleMask.miniaturizable, NSWindow.StyleMask.resizable]
   }
   ```
2. extension for changing NSView background color

   ```
   extension NSView {

       @IBInspectable var backgroundColor: NSColor {
           get {
               let cgColor = self.layer?.backgroundColor
               let result = NSColor(cgColor: (cgColor)!)
               return (result)!
           }

           set {
               self.wantsLayer = true
               self.layer?.backgroundColor = newValue.cgColor
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Settings of the window controller:

[image]

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: Hi @UpholderOfTruth, I've added some code. Please check if there are problems.

Comment: That shows how the background, etc is setup but the problem lies with the buttons so how are they setup and added?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, I added screenshot of the window controller's setting. Close, Minimize and Resize are checked. Also, in the windowDidLoad(), you can see the styleMasks for the three buttons.

Comment: Well I'm an iOS guy move than a Mac guy development wise but I set up a basic project using what I think are your settings and it works fine.  Any other code, info, settings, etc that might help narrow it down.  E.g where do you set the views background colour?

Comment: Hi @UpholderOfTruth, thanks for your warm heart. I solved this by checking the 'Title Bar' and 'Full Size Content View'. But still don't know what's the difference between doing this and the setting programmatically.

Comment: No problem sometimes even discussing the problem helps to fix it yourself.